# How to count array with group by

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 226
            [city] => Dhaka
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 228
            [city] => Charleston County
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 229
            [city] => Dhaka
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 232
            [city] => Dhaka
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 234
            [city] => Miami-Dade County
        )
```

Here city Dhaka for 3 times

so I want my result as Dhaka=3 , Miami-Dade County=1,Charleston County=1

this is a sample array all data will come dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over the array and count the instances of each city as you go.

```
$city_counts = array();                            // create an array to hold the counts
foreach ($array as $city_object) {                 // loop over the array of city objects
// checking isset will prevent undefined index notices    
if (isset($city_counts[$city_object->city])) {            
        $city_counts[$city_object->city]++;        // increment the count for the city
    } else {
        $city_counts[$city_object->city] = 1;      // initialize the count for the city
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP >= 5.3.0:

```
$result = array_count_values(array_map(function($v) {
                                           return $v->city;
                                       }, $array));
```

For earlier versions (Oh why?) you need to build a function for `array_map()` or loop through the array and build a single-dimensional one to count.

Comment: No problem. It's too bad it won't. It's such a handy function.